# how to replace faulty root disk in svm

Tags: solaris

I am solaris system administrator.I have a query about disk replacement in svm.
If I want to replace a faulty 'rootdisk' (primary boot disk) from svm ,provided the rootmirror disk is good ,then

should i do the following ?

```
 query1)  ----->       `#>  init 0`
                      `ok>  boot <rootmirror>`         (as rootdisk is faulty)
                     (and then replace the faulty rootdisk)
```

OR should i just do the following ?

```
query2)  ----->           `eeprom boot-device="rootmirror rootdisk"`
                     (without booting from rootmirror  )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you planning to replace the root disk while the system is running ? i.e. hot-swapping ?

Comment: yes MelBurslan ,while the system is running.

Comment: But in that case if you use the `init 0` command you will shut down your system. Is that what you really want to do ? I do not suggest messing with root disk while the system is running, regardless of the UNIX flavor but if you want to take that chance, you know that your boot device is dead and your system is reaching out to the mirror device, you may not even have to do either of the choices you mentioned, but if you crash in the process your system will not automatically boot and you will have to use command `boot <rootmirror>` at the `ok>` prompt.at the boot time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you are asking. So I will first address, what is for me, the mistake in your logic.

Your first option will only boot the system if the SVM metadbs are over 50%. Traditionally, both boot disks have metadbs. If you lost one disk and you reboot the system, it will stop because it does not have 50% of the metadbs in a stable condition. See more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-6111/6jf2ve3nb/index.html).

Your second option is in fact pointless. You don't need to change the boot order when you are replacing the disk online.

To replace the disk itself, Oracle has clear defined way to do so. I have done it multiple times wihtout a hitch from Solaris 8 upwards.
Overall the procedure is as follows:

1. Delete metadbs that were on the failed disks,
2. Replace the failed disk as per service instructions for the server,
3. Copy the partition table from the mirror disk to the replaced disks,
4. Use metareplace to replace the submirrors,
5. Install boot block on the new disk,
6. Create the metadbs on the new disk.

Step-by-step instructions can also be found [here](http://thegeekdiary.com/how-to-replace-failed-root-disk-under-solaris-volume-manager-svm/).

If you wish indeed to reboot the system, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-4520/troubleshoottasks-29.html#troubleshoottasks-21051).

Wait for the synchronization to finish before doing further maintenance.

Comment: Ok thanks for the detailed answer.My dought was that,if I remove primary disk for replacement,will it not cause the OS to be crashed as our active root file system is on that disk .

Comment: for what it's worth, I've taken up a policy of explicitly setting an *uneven* number of replicas on dual mirrored root disks. Then my odds of booting after a failed hard drive go from 0% to 50%.